# Data not copied to register

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am new to Verilog and I am stuck in a problem. I don't what I am doing wrong. I have two modules (A and B). Module B do some processing and puts value in register 'Data' which is output of module B and acts as input of module A. Module A compares the value in Data and sends a signal to reset the register 'Data' in module B. Data processed in module B exists and is correct while it is not appearing in module A.

```
ModuleB (address,indata,Data,reset,clk,ResetSignal,Out)
input  [15:0] address;
input  [15:0] indata;
input        ResetSignal;
output [5:0] Data;
output [15:0] Data;

reg[15:0] DataReceived;
reg[0:5]  Data = 6'b000000;
reg[15:0]  Out;

if(address == 16'h01a0) 
 begin
  DataReceived<= indata;
  Data = (Data| 6'b000001); // all 6 values will be copied on basis of some address
 end
.
.
.

ModuleA (...)

reg[15:0] address;
reg[15:0] indata;
reg[15:0] Out;
reg  ResetSignal;
reg[5:0] Data; //it is an internal register of module B which contains data received from module B

wire reset,clk;

ModuleB (.address(address),.indata(indata),.Data(Data),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.ResetSignal(ResetSignal),.Out(Out));

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
 if (reset)
    ResetSignal = 1'b0;
 else if (Data == 6'b111111)
  begin
    //set some signals 
    ResetSignal = 1'b1; // send signal back to reset the buffer Data
  end
end
```

I have declared Data as reg so values from Module B should be mapped. Shouldn't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `reg[5:0] Data` as a register in `ModuleA`, and connected to the output of your module `ModuleB`:

```
ModuleB moduleBInstance(.address(address),.indata(indata),.Data(Data),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.ResetSignal(ResetSignal),.Out(Out));
```

(I added an instance name here, I assume there is an instance name here but you forget to write it here, otherwise simulation would not accept it.)

Some verilog synthesizers would not accept connecting a net of `reg` type to the output of modules because you cannot assign to a reg asynchronously. If you change the type for the net `Data` in `ModuleA` to wire (`wire[5:0] Data`). You should be able to assign to it.

Comment: yes that was the issue! I have changed reg to wire in moduleA and it is working now. Thank you. I have instance name, i have copied a piece of problematic code only so missed that :)

Answer (score 1):

You have left out portions of your code, otherwise I would simulate it, but here is what I notice to begin with:

In module B you have two output registers call Data.  The inputs and outputs need to have unique names.

It looks like in module A you define Data as a reg[5:0].  You need to declare that as a wire [5:0].  Module B has the register, so module A is just a wire.

Start with that and then post your complete code along with a test bench if you have one.

Comment: Changing reg to wire worked!! I have just posted the portion of code causing issue.